# How to make the label next to an input tag equal the placeholder

Tags: jquery, html

I was just trying to figure out how to imitate the input's placeholder in the nearest label tag.
jQuery is the way of course.

My code looks something like this:

```
<div class="group">
   <input placeholder="first" >
   <label> First </label
</div>

<div class="group">
   <input placeholder="second" >
   <label> second </label
</div>
```

EDIT:

Check this Codepen:

https://codepen.io/afasanistan/pen/mRmEwm?editors=1010

Comment: ok, check this codepen: https://codepen.io/afasanistan/pen/mRmEwm?editors=1010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery [`after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) method with a callback function.

```js
$('.group input').after(function() {
  // generate the label need to put after the element
  return '<label>' + this.placeholder + '</label>';
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="group">
  <input placeholder="first">
</div>

<div class="group">
  <input placeholder="second">
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, Thanks, I don't know why didn't I think of that, Really thank you.

Comment: @AlyHassan : glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

1 - Give an ID to your inputs. I'm assuming  `#input1 / #input2`

2-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var sd = $('#input1').attr('placeholder');  
    $('label[for^=input1]') = sd ;  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this browser-specific CSS rules for this to work or you can use jquery to script the behavior.

```css
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  text-align: right;
}
::-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 19+ */
  text-align: right;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder {
  /* IE 10+ */
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="group">
  <input placeholder="first">
  <label>First</label>
</div>

<div class="group">
  <input placeholder="second">
  <label>second</label>
</div>
```

[for more info](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/p/placeholder/)